# Creating pandas dataframe from list of dictionaries containing lists of data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries with this structure.

```
    {
        'data' : [[year1, value1], [year2, value2], ... m entries],
        'description' : string,
        'end' : string,
        'f' : string,
        'lastHistoricalperiod' : string, 
        'name' : string,
        'series_id' : string,
        'start' : int,
        'units' : string,
        'unitsshort' : string,
        'updated' : string
    }
```

I want to put this in a pandas DataFrame that looks like

```
   year       value  updated                   (other dict keys ... )
0  2040  120.592468  2014-05-23T12:06:16-0400  other key-values
1  2039  120.189987  2014-05-23T12:06:16-0400  ...
2  other year-value pairs ...
...
n
```

where n = m* len(list with dictionaries) (where length of each list in 'data' = m)

That is, each tuple in 'data' should have its own row.  What I've done thus far is this:

```
x = [list of dictionaries as described above]
# Create Empty Data Frame
output = pd.DataFrame()

    # Loop through each dictionary in the list
    for dictionary in x:
        # Create a new DataFrame from the 2-D list alone.
        data = dictionary['data']
        y = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['year', 'value'])
        # Loop through all the other dictionary key-value pairs and fill in values
        for key in dictionary:
            if key != 'data':
                y[key] = dictionary[key]
        # Concatenate most recent output with the dframe from this dictionary.
        output = pd.concat([output_frame, y], ignore_index = True)
```

This seems very hacky, and I was wondering if there's a more 'pythonic' way to do this, or at least if there are any obvious speedups here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Your data is in the form `[{},{},...]` you can do the following...

The issue with your data is in the data key of your dictionaries.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fix = df.groupby(level=0)['data'].apply(lambda x:pd.DataFrame(x.iloc[0],columns = ['Year','Value']))
fix = fix.reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
df = pd.merge(fix,df.drop(['data'],1),how='inner',left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

The code does the following...

1. Creates a DataFrame with your list of dictionaries
2. creates a new dataframe by stretching out your data column into more rows
3. The stretching line has caused a multiindex with an irrelevant column - this removes it
4. Finally merge on the original index and get desired DataFrame

Comment: I like this solution a lot.  Since everything begins in a dataframe, there's very little opportunity for modifications to the code to decouple each 'data' list with the other heading information.

Answer (score 0):

Some data would have been helpful when answering this question. However, from your data structure some example data might look like this:

```
dict_list = [{'data'            : [['1999', 1], ['2000', 2], ['2001', 3]],
              'description'     : 'foo_dictionary',
              'end'             : 'foo1',
              'f'               : 'foo2',},
             {'data'            : [['2002', 4], ['2003', 5]],
              'description'     : 'bar_dictionary',
              'end'             : 'bar1',
              'f'               : 'bar2',}
             ]
```

My suggestion would be to manipulate and reshape this data into a new dictionary and then simply pass that dictionary to the DataFrame constructor. In order to pass a dictionary to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor you could very simply reshape the data into a new dict as follows:

```
data_dict = {'years'        : [],
             'value'        : [],
             'description'  : [],
             'end'          : [],
             'f'            : [],}

for dictionary in dict_list:
    data_dict['years'].extend([elem[0] for elem in dictionary['data']])
    data_dict['value'].extend([elem[1] for elem in dictionary['data']])
    data_dict['description'].extend(dictionary['description'] for x in xrange(len(dictionary['data'])))
    data_dict['end'].extend(dictionary['end'] for x in xrange(len(dictionary['data'])))
    data_dict['f'].extend(dictionary['f'] for x in xrange(len(dictionary['data'])))
```

and then just pass this to pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

which gives me the following output:

```
      description   end     f  value years
0  foo_dictionary  foo1  foo2      1  1999
1  foo_dictionary  foo1  foo2      2  2000
2  foo_dictionary  foo1  foo2      3  2001
3  bar_dictionary  bar1  bar2      4  2002
4  bar_dictionary  bar1  bar2      5  2003
```

I would say that if this is the type of output you want, then this system would be a decent simplification.

In fact you could simplify it even further by creating a year:value dictionary, and a dict for the other vals. Then you would not have to type out the new dictionary and you could run a nested for loop. This could look as follows:

```
year_val_dict = {'years'        : [],
                 'value'        : []}
other_val_dict = {_key : [] for _key in dict_list[0] if _key!='data'}

for dictionary in dict_list:
    year_val_dict['years'].extend([elem[0] for elem in dictionary['data']])
    year_val_dict['value'].extend([elem[1] for elem in dictionary['data']])
    for _key in other_val_dict:
        other_val_dict[_key].extend(dictionary[_key] for x in xrange(len(dictionary['data'])))

year_val_dict.update(other_val_dict)
pd.DataFrame(year_val_dict)
```

NB this of course assumes that all the dicts in the dict_list have the same structure....